# Logging X-forward-for on ATS

Tags: linux, apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, apache-traffic-server

Is there a configuration setting I can do to make Apache traffic server to log XFF header into the logs ? I have gone over the ATS documentation and there's no mention of this. I see various logging formats explained.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [custom log field](https://docs.trafficserver.apache.org/en/latest/admin-guide/logging/formatting.en.html?#admin-logging-fields-headers) 'cqh' you can log the value of any header. So in your logging.config, you'd have a field '%<{X-Forwarded-For}cqh>'